# Help with the chain rule (physics example)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, physics

I post this topic here, because I need help with the math.

I having problem with the chain rule in the derivation of the effective mass. I don't understand one step in the last equation below. Thanks in advance!

The derivation: Given:
$$E=\frac{\hbar k^2}{2m} \text{,}  \qquad F=\hbar\frac{dk}{dt}$$
$$ k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\text{,}\qquad v_g=\frac{1}{\hbar}\frac{dE}{dk}$$
The constant $\hbar$ is $\frac{h}{2\pi}$.

Take derivative of $v_g$ with respect to $t$ so
$$
\frac{dv_g}{dt}=\frac{1}{\hbar}\frac{d}{dt}\frac{dE}{dk}=\frac{1}{\hbar}\underbrace{
\frac{{d^2E}}{dk^2}\frac{dk}{dt}
}_\text{Why and how?}
=\frac{1}{\hbar^2}\frac{d^2E}{dk^2}F$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that the chain rule states that if $y = g(x)$, then $$\left.\frac{d}{dx}(f\circ g)\right|_{x_0} = \left.\frac{df}{dy}\right|_{g(x_0)}\cdot \left.\frac{dg}{dx}\right|_{x_0}$$

---

In your setup, $k$ is *implicitly* a function of time $t$.  So let's make it a little more explicit.  Let $\color{blue}{k} = \color{red}{k}(t)$ (that is we're "overloading" the symbol $k$ so that it can represent a $\color{blue}{\text{variable}}$ or a $\color{red}{\text{function}}$ -- this is so I don't have to make up a new variable name).

Then we have $$\frac{d}{dt}\left.\left(\frac{dE}{d\color{blue}{k}}\circ \color{red}{k}\right)\right|_{t} = \frac{d}{d\color{blue}{k}}\left.\left(\frac{dE}{d\color{blue}{k}}\right)\right|_{\color{red}{k}(t)}\cdot\left.\frac{d\color{red}{k}}{dt}\right|_{t} = \left.\frac{d^2E}{d\color{blue}{k}^2}\right|_{\color{red}{k}(t)}\cdot\left.\frac{d\color{red}{k}}{dt}\right|_{t}$$

by the chain rule.

Comment: If my color-coding has just made this more confusing, let me know and I'll define a new variable to represent the argument of $E$.

Comment: Thank you! This was very confusing and no book clarified that $k$ was a function of $t$. I thought [$k$ always was a scalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavenumber#Definition). Your color-coding was great! Just for curiosity, what do you mean with define a new variable for E? Never seen that alternative in any books.

Comment: With your $k=k(t)$, is it correct to write the given expressions explicit as $E=E(k)=\frac{\hbar k(t)^2}{2m}, 
F=F(t)=\hbar\frac{dk(t)}{dt}$ and $
v_g=v_g(t)=\frac{1}{\hbar}\frac{dE(k)}{dk}$?

Comment: You can call the argument of a function whatever you like.  So for instance $E(k) = \frac{\hbar k^2}{2m}$ (mathematically) means exactly the same thing as $E(q) = \frac{\hbar q^2}{2m}$.  The name of the argument has no real meaning.  $k$ would normally be fine as a variable name, except that we're also using it as the name of a function.  So I could have distinguished between the two different meanings of the $k$'s in your problem better if I had changed your $E(k)$ formula to my $E(q)$ formula.

Comment: It's a little abusive of the notation to write $E(k)=\frac{\hbar k(t)^2}{2m}$ as the LHS is a function of $k$ but the RHS is a function of $t$.  But (speaking as a physicist) physicists don't usually worry about being absolutely rigorous with our statements.  So the equations you've given are fine.

Comment: Ah okey! For a beginner the lack of rigor is sometimes confusing. Speaking of abusive of the notation, is $E(t)$ a more correct notation or even $E$?

Comment: $(E\circ k)(t)$ or $\left.E\right|_{k(t)}$ would be the best notations, but you'll never see that in physics.  Most often you'll see $E(t)$ (even sometimes in math you'll see this).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I thought;

$$ \frac{dv_g}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dE}{dk}) \cdot \frac{1}{\hbar} $$

As $k$ is a function of $t$ (by the statements initially stated),then the chain rule may be applied;

$$ \frac{dv_g}{dt}=\frac{d}{dk}(\frac{dE}{dk}) \cdot \frac{dk}{dt} \cdot \frac{1}{\hbar} $$

$$\frac{dE}{dk} =f(k),\\ 
\therefore \frac{d}{dk}(\frac{dE}{dk}) = \frac{d^2E}{dk^2}$$

Hence the overall problem may be reduced to;

$$ \frac{dv_g}{dt}= \frac{d^2E}{dk^2} \cdot \frac{dk}{dt} \cdot \frac{1}{\hbar} $$

As $\frac{dk}{dt}=\frac{F}{\hbar}$, the overall result becomes;

$$ \frac{dv_g}{dt}= \frac{d^2E}{dk^2} \cdot \frac{F}{\hbar^2} \equiv \frac{1}{\hbar^2} \cdot \frac{d^2E}{dk^2} \cdot F $$

I think this is correct.

Hope this helps.